# Logging to App Engine request_log through Logback

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logback, java-11, google-cloud-logging

I've got an app built on the *Ninja Framework* using App Engine Standard Environment - Java 11, using the injected Logger that comes with Ninja, which is *Apache Logback*. Normally, this logs to the `stdout` of the instance, so all my messages come in one-line-per-entry format, and on the `stdout` log channel, which is less than convenient when trying to trace a bug in production.

There *is* a guide up on Google's documentation for logging to Stackdriver with Logback [1], and I've tried this, to no effect: logs now end up in `application.log`, which is still a separate channel, and the `request_log` channel is empty.
I've tried changing up the recommended configuration by putting `projects/dive-site-overwatch/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log` as the `<log>` element in `logback.xml`, which caused all requests to fail because of an "invalid format" on the URL-encoded solidus. Conversely, adding the solidus as-is causes an exception by being an illegal character.

My current Logback config that I have deployed is the following (you can tell I'm running out of ideas...):

```
<configuration>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />

    <appender name = "STDOUT" class = "ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="tech.provingground.dive_overwatch.etc.logging.layouts.StackdriverLayout">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name = "CLOUD" class = "com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <log>application.log</log> <!-- Optional : default java.log -->
        <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
        <enhancer>tech.provingground.dive_overwatch.etc.logging.enhancers.TestEnhancer</enhancer>
        <encoder>
            <layout class="tech.provingground.dive_overwatch.etc.logging.layouts.StackdriverLayout">
                <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg</pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level = "info">
        <appender-ref ref = "CLOUD" />
<!--        <appender-ref ref = "STDOUT" />-->
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Looking at the standard out of the application, I can see a number of loglines that point to rejected requests from Stackdriver:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 6 seconds for com.google.common.util.concurrent.CollectionFuture$ListFuture@77fbc3ba[status=PENDING, info=[futures=[[com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture@772ddfb8, com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture@7d905614, com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture@7396512d, com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture@5ad9baf6]]]]
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.flush(LoggingImpl.java:581)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.write(LoggingImpl.java:562)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.append(LoggingAppender.java:215)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender.append(LoggingAppender.java:70)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
[...]
```

I could understand a 403 or similar status code if it was an authentication error, but the Standard Environment is supposed to provide the service account, as well as automatically grant the *Logs Writer* role.

I'm kind of stumped here. Is there any way to have my application logs in the same place as the rest of my request logs, in the regular `request_log`?

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java#logback_appender_for

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this [example](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#run_manual_logging-java) that does JSON logging with logback!  The key element is that it includes the Trace ID so that the message correlates with the request log.

From the sample:

```
// Build structured log messages as an object.
Object globalLogFields = null;
// Add log correlation to nest all log messages beneath request log in Log Viewer.
String traceHeader = req.headers("x-cloud-trace-context");
if (traceHeader != null && project != null) {
  String trace = traceHeader.split("/")[0];
  globalLogFields =
      kv(
          "logging.googleapis.com/trace",
          String.format("projects/%s/traces/%s", project, trace));
}
// Create a structured log entry using key value pairs.
logger.error(
    "This is the default display field.",
    kv("component", "arbitrary-property"),
    kv("severity", "NOTICE"),
    globalLogFields);
```

Comment: That's _one step_ closer to what I'm looking to achieve, but it's still not putting the log lines in the same entry as the request. Not even when I add a field like `StructuredArgument logNameField = kv("logging.googleapis.com/logName", String.format("projects/%s/logs/%s", project, "appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"));`, they are still placed on the stdout.